# Where I can find a complete list of all predefined variables of docker-in-docker?

Tags: docker, variables

so the question is where can I find the list of predefined docker variables? I've been looking for 4 hours already, official site, google, dockerhub with docker image...no answer.

UPD. @Saeed thank you for reply, docs.docker.com was the first place I visited, but not found what I need. For example I know this vars: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR, DOCKER_HOST and several more.

Comment: As you know, https://docs.docker.com/ is the best reference, but what do you mean by predefined vars? Can you elaborate it with some examples by editing your question?

Comment: @Saeed thank you for answer, edited question. Hope it helps you or other guys to clearly understand my question

Comment: You want only for **docker** image? Or you mean for all of the images?

Comment: @Saeed only for *docker* image. Specially I need log level variable, but really wish a complete list of variables if it exists.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you

Comment: no problem, thank you for participating